# Unable to Use Transactions with Go statement in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, batch-file

```
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
Go

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.RerurnStaticValue
(
@value nvarchar(10)
)
RETURNS varchar(max)
AS 
   BEGIN

      DECLARE
         @ReturnValue nvarchar(10)
         SET @ReturnValue = @value
         RETURN @ReturnValue
    END  
        COMMIT TRAN -- Transaction Success!
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        ROLLBACK TRAN --RollBack in case of Error
    select ERROR_MESSAGE()
END CATCH
```

I am preparing a very long script and try to implement the transaction in the script so in case if there will be any error in my script it will not effect my database. But I am getting the error *Create function must be the only statement in the batch* when implementing transactions.

Please help.

Comment: `GO` is not an SQL Keyword, it is just a batch separator in SSMS, so all it does is split your script into chunks and process them separately. So a single transaction cannot span multiple batches. From the above though, it is not really clear why you want to. You aren't actually touching any data...

Comment: Why do you need a transaction here? You would need to exec() a `create function` string, it clearly tells you *Create function must be the only statement in the batch*.  (`GO` is a special keyword only for utilities such as SSMS to indicate the end of a batch)

Answer (score 0):

I think the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx) on functions is pretty clear:

> User-defined functions cannot be used to perform actions that modify
>   the database state.

`COMMIT`/`ROLLBACK` definitely fall into this category.

Use a stored procedure instead.